# Is it possible to recover Ubuntu 16.04 and install mysql after running "sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;"?

Tags: mysql, file-recovery

By mistake, I executed this command "sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;" on my system (Ubuntu 16.04).
Is there any way that I can recover the dependencies and install again mysql? 
I found this command here "https://help.cloud66.com/maestro/how-to-guides/databases/shells/uninstall-mysql.html".

Comment: That means all mysql related has been deleted from server. You have to reinstall mysql again.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that will face this problem in the future (certainly hope not), I succeed to solve it via aptitude and recover one by one the dependencies.